# Generating browser application bundles (phase: sealing)...runtime: out of memory: cannot allocate 4194304-byte block

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a build getting this error:

> Generating browser application bundles (phase: sealing)...runtime: out
> of memory: cannot allocate 4194304-byte block (24772608 in use) fatal
> error: out of memory

and when i delete my `node_modules` then 2 times i can generate the build. But after that, I am getting the same error.

Angular version that i'm using :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough context about the causes of the issue. This is might be the result of one of the libraries or dependencies you are using in your project which leads to a memory peek during build. [You can follow up a discussion on similar issue here on Github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19526#issuecomment-738664547)

Comment: i have tried this link but same error should i change the angular cli version?

Comment: I still think that you have a high size package among your dependencies. But yes, you can try to downgrade or upgrade your ng version. https://angular.io/cli/update